# Greater latitude and longitude values

Tags: google-maps, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I came across a dataset which has Latitude values in the range (0,181.763) i.e. minimum latitude is 0 degree and maximum latitude is 181.763 degree and Longitude values in the range (228.722,242.008) i.e. minimum latitude is 228.722 degree and maximum latitude is 242.008 degree. Is there some way by which I may confine the latitude and longitude's to correct boundaries?

Comment: Longitude > 180 deg I can understand, but latitude?  That doesn't make sense.  Are the units something other than degrees?

Comment: @JimLewis I am afraid, the units are in  degrees

Comment: Latitude 0,181   if  ',' the decimal separator?

Comment: @scaisEdge I mean the range of Latitude is from 0 to 181.763 with minimum Latitude 0 and maximum latitude 181.763

Comment: These value in normal google maps coords are wrong  .. where this dataset come from? .. wichh kind of data or coordinates system are used?

Comment: @scaisEdge The dataset was collected by my company :) The coordinates are in degrees.

Comment: @scaisEdge No it is not from GPS

Answer (score 0):

well if they are spherical coordinates, long 181.763deg points in the same direction as -178.237deg or 361.763deg, depending on the conventions used

to transform latitude ranges of (228.722,242.008) to (-90,90) the transformation matrix to use is ((x-228.722)/0.073811)-90 for each point x. for example 229.3deg gives -82.169deg

it could be that you are using slightly scaled (elliptical) polar coordinates and you can transform them back by division...